# php detect function is called

Tags: php, function

I dont know how to explain this question so maybe the tile is not matched.

```
    Class a {
       function b{
         return $this;
       }
       function c{
         return $this;
       }
    }
```

If I have class structure like this I can do

```
$a = new a();
$a->b()->c();
```

I want to know how can I know the function is not continued like `$a->b();`, then I return $retuslt instead of $this.

```
Class a {
   function b{

     //if not continued
     return $result;

     //if continued
     return $this;

   }
   function c{
     return $this;
   }
}
```

Is this possible? thank you very much!!

Comment: I don't think you can do that within PHP. Why would you need to?

Comment: if that is not possible, that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You will not know inside the method what is being done with the return. You could however pass a return value in, for example:

```
Class a {
   function b(&$return){
     // do something 
     $return = 'some value';
     return $this;
   }
   function c(){
     return $this;
   }
}



$a = new a();
$a->b($returnFromB)->c();
echo $returnFromB; // 'some value'
```

Comment: Thank you, I just want to know if its possible.